# Keylogger with Persian and English keymap on Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, log

I want to log which characters I use most in a day and to log all pressed keys in all application.

How I do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: see here and read key and save it seperately http://blog.efazati.org/post/%DA%86%D9%86%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%AF%DA%A9%D9%85%D9%87-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%DA%A9%DB%8C%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D9%81%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AF%D8%9F

Comment: @Efazati thanks dude but I would like to log like as a keylogger app :) your script is just counter

Comment: change a little ... in some line, script can read key. so store it in somewhere and count each character